# Carousel slider with flexbox, preventing horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make carousel slider using flexbox. 
The issue is that I need to show only 4 items and prevent scrolling, while `.carousel` takes full width and displays all the items with scrolling.
Is it possible to do this using flexbox?

```css
.main - container {
  display: flex;
  flex - direction: row;
  overflow: hidden;
  min - width: 0;
}

.prev,
.next {
  flex: initial;
  width: 50 px;
}

.carousel {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="prev"></div>
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="nex"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PaoloForgia We typically only use Snippets for code that shows something when it's run.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with some slight modification to your code.  I've added flex-grow properties to your three containers in the flex row as well as `overflow: scroll` and `white-space: nowrap` to your carousel and set your `.item` to `display: inline-block`;

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-width: 0;
}

.prev,
.next {
  width: 50 px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

.carousel {
  flex-grow: 2;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  overflow: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
  
.item {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="prev">&laquo;</div>
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/300"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/300"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/300"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/300"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/300"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/300"/></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/300"/></div>
  </div>
  <div class="nex">&raquo;</div>
</div>
```